# Customizing fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr, parts

I am trying to get a header set-up, but I'm facing some issues. The way I want to have it displayed is:

(Part Nr.): (Part Name) ---- (Ch nr.). (Chapter name)

The header should be displayed on all pages except the page where the new part starts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{Part one}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[1-4]
\part{Part two}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`report` does not provide marks for the part level. You could use `scrreprt` and `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `report` and `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{headings}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\chead{}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightmark}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{headings}% use headings page style also for chapter pages

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}
\blinddocument
\part{Second Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: example with scrreprt and scrlayer-scrpage]

If `scrreprt` should by more lookalike to `report` you can use option `emulatestandardclasses`:

```
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses,autooneside=false]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
\pagestyle{headings}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\chead{}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightmark}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{headings}% use headings page style also for chapter pages

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}
\blinddocument
\part{Second Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: more like report]

If you want a head separation line, you can use option `headsepline`. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information on the configuration of KOMA-Script classes or package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Note: You should not use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class like `scrreprt`. You should use the KOMA-Script features to configure the sectioning commands instead.

To get the same with `report` you have to patch the class:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{headings}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\chead{}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightmark}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{\@endpart}{%
  \partmark{#2}%
  \@endpart
}{}{}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\partmarkformat}{\thepart.\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter.\enskip}

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}{}% dont use pagestyle plain for chapter pages

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}
\blinddocument
\part{Second Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: example using report and scrlayer-scrpage]

Note: You cannot combine `fancyhdr` and `scrlayer-scrpage`. So if you use `scrlayer-scrpage` to configure the page headings like shown above, you must not load `fancyhdr`!

But if you absolutely want to use `fancyhdr` you can replace the `scrlayer-scrpage` code of the last example by some `fancyhdr` code, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{\@endpart}{%
  \partmark{#2}%
  \@endpart
}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand*{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{\thepart.\enskip \MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter.\enskip \MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}{}% dont use pagestyle plain for chapter pages

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}
\blinddocument
\part{Second Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note: If you are using package `titlesec` you have to use `\renewcommand` to (re)define `\partmark`. And patching `\@part` may fail, if you use `titlesec` to redefine `\part`. And patching `\chapter` may fail, if you use `titlesec` to redefine `\chapter`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the header style using your second example, with scrreprt class, without scrlayer-scrpage. There is a slight difference with the original layout however, I'm not exactly sure what, but my introduction fitted exactly on one page and has now 1 line on the next page. Also, I get a lot of errors about \bf, but the document does compile. Lastly, I want a line underneath the header as with fancyref, and no header on the 'special' pages such as ToC and References

Comment: @Tristan: `\bf` should not be used anymore. Use either `\bfseries` or `\textbf{…}` or `\normalfont\bfseries`. And `scrreprt` with option `emulatestandardclasses` is still not exactly the same as the standard class `report`. But you can change most things and use, e.g, package `geometry` to change the margins. For the line in the page header see my note about `headsepline`.

Comment: I should have clearified: I don't use the `\bf `, but it is encoutered in the ToC, apparently

Comment: Then you are using a package, that uses `\bf` and should not. Make a bug report to the author of that package. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc KOMA-Script itself does not use `\bf` for the ToC. However, if using a KOMA-Script class is a problem in your case, see the `report` solutions in my answer.

Comment: Found it, there was a `\bf` somewhere after all. You are great. Last question: the header still appears at ToC and bibliography, how can I remove it on those pages?

Comment: @Tristan: [This would be another question.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2117) However: You can change the page style wherever you want using, e.g., `\pagestyle{plain}` and `\thispagestyle{plain}`. Note, that ToC etc. are chapters too and at `scrreprt` therefore use `\thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}` themselves. So you either have to redefine `\chapterpagestyle` too or use something like `\AfterTOCHead{\thispagestyle{plain}\pagestyle{plain}`. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about these commands.